# React - Redirect not working after api call

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`.

So after making an API post request, on the success I want to move back to the homepage.

Any ideas what's wrong with the following:

```
try {
      const resp = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add', page);
      if (resp.status == 200) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Ok, I read that the `Redirect` has to be in render.
So in my functional component, I've added a boolean for redirect which I update once the POST request has been successful.

However this doesn't seem to be valid:

```
if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />
}
```

As I get the error: `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>`

Thanks.

Comment: alternatively, you can try and use `history`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to use `setState` to make the state change and `Redirect` in `render`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  async foo () {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add', page);
      if (resp.status == 200) {
        this.setState({redirect:true})
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

     if (redirect) {
       return <Redirect to='/'/>;
     }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yep I've read something similar, but I still get an error - I've updated my question..

Comment: I hope `Router` is enclosing your component

Comment: It is - but I now see the error `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` followed by `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.`

Comment: Ah - it had to be `BrowserRouter` so `<BrowserRouter><Redirect to='/'/></BrowserRouter>`
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice, Cheers mate :D